# How to integrate $\int{1\over \sqrt{x^2-1}}\mathrm d x$ another technique without use trigonometry

Tags: calculus, integration, alternative-proof

How can I integrate $\int{1\over \sqrt{x^2-1}}\mathrm d x$ without using trygnometry? I mean using other methods like substituition, integration by parts (I tried these two but I think I am not seeing the best way to integrate. I reached some integrals more complicated.

Comment: Sure that you mean $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}-1}dx}$ and not $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx}$ ? Otherwise it becomes pretty trivial i believe.

Comment: Is it $\int{{dx}\over \sqrt{x^2}-1}$ or $\int{{dx}\over \sqrt{x^2-1}}$ ? If it is the second one, try $x=\cosh(t)$

Comment: One instinct tells me to divide the integral into cases where $x > 0$ or $x \leq 0$. This way, you will obtain two easy integrals (natural logarithm).

Comment: Trigonometric substitution is a form of $u$-substitution.

Comment: K. Hoffmann you is rigth i wrote wrong, actually is  sqrt(x²-1). Thank you.

Comment: But have another way? i mean a method that for example you get a fraction function something like this??

Comment: In this case hyperbolic substitution (Claude's comment) works better, because it's $x^2-1$ under the root and not $1-x^2$

Comment: The methods often used in elementary calculus are $x = \sec\theta$ and $x = \cosh t$ (as Clauce Leibovici says); both convert a difference of squares to a perfect square, and lead to fairly short calculations. When you say "substitution didn't work", it might be a good idea to say specifically what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: I tried to do the first euler substitution, calling sqrt(x²-1) = x + t and then using the integral under the variable t but i probably missed some calculations i will try again this method. Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume $x>1$ and write
$${1\over\sqrt{x^2-1}}={1\over\sqrt{x^2-1}}\>{\sqrt{x^2-1}+x\over \sqrt{x^2-1}+x}={1+{x\over\sqrt{x^2-1}}\over x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}={u'(x)\over u(x)}$$
with $u(x):=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}>0$. It follows that
$$\int{dx\over\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\log\bigl(u(x)\bigr)+C=\log\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\bigr)+C\ .$$

Comment: Ingenious idea I must say. I never thought it this way.